# C++ fmtlib : How to convert a double to existing wchar_t buffer?

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm considering transitioning from snprintf and its ilk to fmtlib.
Imagine this fictional code:

```
class CFoo
{
  size_t  m_szLen{0};
  wchar_t m_pwcDst[123]{};
  ...

public:
  void Bar(double dValue, uint8 u8TotDecimals)
  {
    m_szLen += swprintf_s(&m_pwcDst[m_szLen], _countof(m_pwcDst)-m_szLen, L"%.*f", u8TotDecimals, dValue);
  }
};
```

How would I convert this to fmtlib WITHOUT copying std::wstring or fmt_memory_buffer?
So, I want fmt::format_to to use my existing buffer.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] where you _do_ the copy that you want to avoid?

Comment: Something like this:
```
std::wstring wstrTmp = fmt::format(L"{:.{}f}", dValue, u8TotDecimals);
wcsncpy(m_pwcDst, _countof(m_pwcDst)-m_u32Len, wstrTmp.c_str();
m_u32Len += wstrTmp.length();
```
Why doesn't the 'source code' marker not work in this comment?!? It should be outlined like source code.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. From the link: "_Your code examples should be ... Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself_"

Comment: This site uses a Question/Answer format, please do not put answers in the question box. You can write answers in the answer box. (I have rolled back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as simple/clear as I would have hoped, so that's a shame. But, this might do what I want:

```
class CFoo
{
  size_t  m_szLen{0};
  wchar_t m_pwcDst[123]{};
  ...

public:
  void Bar(double dValue, uint8 u8TotDecimals)
  {
    m_pwcDst[m_szLen += std::min(_countof(m_pwcDst)-m_szLen-1, fmt::format_to_n(&m_pwcDst[m_szLen], _countof(m_pwcDst)-m_szLen, FMT_STRING(L"{:.{}f}"), dValue, u8TotDecimals).size)] = L'\0';
  }
};
```

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be `fmt::format_to_n(n_pwcDst + m_u32Len, ...)`? And `.size` returns the size that would have been printed without truncation. You can't use it  safely to add the terminator.

Comment: I changed it to &m_pwcDst[m_u32Len].
Regarding the size... ooooooooh no! I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The closest function there is to `swprintf_s()` in fmtlib is `fmt::format_to_n()`. However, it returns the number of characters that *would* have been written, so you have to take some care using it. Here is how it would look:

```
void CFoo::Add(double dValue, uint8 u8TotDecimals)
{
    if(pwcSrc) {
        auto space_left = _countof(m_pwcDst) - m_u32Len;
        auto result = fmt::format_to_n(&m_pcwDst, space_left, "{:.{}f}", u8TotDecimals, dValue);
        m_u32Len += std::min(result.size, space_left);
    }
}
```

However, if you want to do things the proper C++ way, then try to see if you can change the destination buffer to be a `std::wstring`, and just add directly to that, like so:

```
void CFoo::Add(double dValue, uint8 u8TotDecimals)
{
    if(pwcSrc)
        m_pwsDst += fmt::format(L"{:.{}f}", u8TotDecimals, dValue);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm a little confused.

Your example with {:.*f} crashes with an exception.

Only if I remove the asterisk which indicates the length I don't get an exception error.

Comment: Ah I forgot to fix the example code, indeed it has to be a `{}` instead of a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

{fmt}'s equivalent of `swprintf_s` is [`format_to_n`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv2N3fmt11format_to_nE8OutputItNSt6size_tERK1SDpRK4Args) which can be used as follows:

```
auto result = fmt::format_to_n(buffer, buffer_size, "{:.{}}", value, precision);
```

In your example `value` is `dValue` and `precision` is `u8TotDecimals`. `result.out` will give you the pointer to the end of the output and `result.size` the total output size if the output wasn't truncated (similarly to `snprintf`).